# Source of TextBoxOnFocus

Tags: c#, winforms, focus

Using C# WinForms, I'm extending TextBox with some extra functionality. Among other things, I'm highlighting the text when the textbox gains focus. This works fine when the user tabs or clicks into the control. However, OnFocus is also called when entire window gains focus (such as alt+tabbing from another app to mine), and this is undesirable.

Any ideas how I can check if the onfocus() is being called because the whole form has gained focus?

Thanks,

Mike

my current OnFocus() looks like:

```
    protected void mTextBox_OnFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (MouseButtons == MouseButtons.None)
        {
            mTextBox.SelectAll();
            mHasFocus = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You might be able to handle the form OnFocus which should occur first. In here you could set a flag or some other indication that the focus has come from the form. Then in the OnFocus of the textbox you can check for the flag.

Comment: hmm perhaps `Onfocus` is not the best suited method to override.

Answer (score 0):

In the GotFocus Event Handler, try checking if the TextBox `Focused` Property is true. See:

[Control.Focused Property - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.focused%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: thanks forr the suggestion, but it doesn't seem to work. Focused is  never true inside OnFocus(), is it?

Comment: @mike, could you post some of the code, like the event handler for the  focus? I just made a small form with a few text boxes and the text would highlight on the desired TextBox when the form came back into focus only if it previously had focus before the form was minimized or moved away from.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the [Control.Capture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.capture.aspx) or [ContainsFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.containsfocus.aspx) properties, to determine wether the Textbox has captured the mouse or contains the focus.

Answer (score 0):

I would sugget you do this:

```
  public class Text : TextBox
  {
    protected override void OnEnter(EventArgs e)
    {
      base.OnEnter(e);
      //To stuff there
    }
  }
```

I have tried several times to control the focus but it is very "slippery". 
Also it is very hard to detirmen where the focus came from - or is going